# Can not export all users in OU from ApacheDS either with studio or ldapsearch

Tags: ldap, apacheds, apache-directory

[image: AD Studio browser settings]I am using Apache DS version 2.0.0.AM24 and have been running it for a couple of months now. Since last week I ran into this issue where I can not export all the users from the OU. I know my OU has about 150K plus users and I can only export only 190 of them, but search for a any user works fine. I tried both Apache Directory studio and ldapsearch but could only export 190 users. I did check my studio browser options and Count limit is set 300k and Time limit is 0. I believe something on my server side changed or corrupted. Any help on how to fix this issue.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure why you can only export 190 entries, but when you want to retrieve over 1000 entries from AD, it is better to use Paged Results Control(RFC2696).

In the case of ldapsearch command, "-Epr=<size>" give you the option with Paged Results.
In this case, <size> should be less than 190.

Comment: Yes it's probably caused by a max. size limit of 190 set on the backend, overcoming this should be ok with `-E pr=190/noprompt` to output the 150k entries by chunks of 190.

Comment: I tried this but did not work ldapsearch -Wx -E pr=190/noprompt -D "uid=admin,ou=system" -b "ou=example,dc=app,dc=org" -H ldap://Hostname:10389 "*" "+" -LLL > users.ldif